# Searching a sentence in paragraph

Tags: python, string, search, replace

Can anyone suggest a way to search for a sentence in a paragraph with python. A paragraph can have 20 sentences. I want a particular sentense is there in paragraph or not

```
key="I want a particular"
parag="what is there to know about.Can anyone suggest a way to search for a sentence in a paragraph with python. A paragraph can have 20 sentences. I want a particular sentense is there in paragraph or not"
```

I want to return true or false, if true need to replace with " found location in paragraph".

Comment: Have you tried `if key in parag:...`?

Comment: @Mark I cant replace or find the location with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
key in parag
```

Will tell you whether your key is in the paragraph or not.  You can also use index to find the location of your key within the paragraph.

```
index = parag.index(key)
```

if key is not in parag then this will raise a ValueError, but if it is then you will get back the index that key starts at within your paragraph.